# browser = webdriver.Chrome() not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting started with Selenium for python and have this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

However it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bradley Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
 File "C:\Users\Bradley 
Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in 
__init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Bradley 
Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in 
_execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bradley Jo\Desktop\Project\app.py", line 3, in 
 <module>
 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Bradley Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
  packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
 self.service.start()
 File "C:\Users\Bradley Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    
 packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
 os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'     
 executable needs to be in PATH. Please see     
 https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

[Finished in 1.0s]
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For windows:

> 1. Check you have installed latest version of chrome browser
> 2. If not, install latest version of chrome
> 3. download the latest(or appropriate) version of chromedriver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
> 4. Paste the `chromedriver.exe` file in `"<Install Dir>/Python27/Scripts"` Folder.

The below code should work now:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be in "<Install Dir>/Python27/Scripts".  It just needs to be somewhere that can be found on your PATH.

Comment: @CoreyG exactly you are right. somewhere that can be found

Comment: @zgg6a please check out the implementation and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

```
'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

It's clear that you need to pass the path of Chrome web driver in `webdriver.Chrome`

```
driver_path = "/Users/amit/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
```

Comment: you don't need to pass the path of chromedriver if it can be found on your PATH (as the error states)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the `Chromedriver.exe`'s path in below command

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.Chrome(Chromedriver.exe's path)
```

Then it starts working

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem comes from your path that contains a space ("Bradley Jo"):

```
C:\Users\Bradley Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py
```

You may try to put your webdriver elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all as follows :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

You need to override any other existing paths and pass the absolute path of the **`chromedriver`** binary as an argument while initializing the **`webdriver`** instance as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put the **chromedriver** in the same folder as your program. That worked for me. Then this code in the python document should suffice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```